# Trigger to update one field (LOCATION) only when two other fields (LATITUDE and LONGITUDE) are inserted/updated?

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I was creating a trigger for this purpose, but I am getting

> table is mutating, trigger/function may not see it

or deadlock warnings if I use it:

```
create or replace TRIGGER fill_coordinates
  BEFORE UPDATE OR DELETE OR INSERT ON bus_stops
  FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN ( ( NEW.latitude <> OLD.latitude OR NEW.longitude <> NEW.longitude ) AND ( NEW.longitude IS NOT NULL AND NEW.latitude IS NOT NULL) )
BEGIN  
  UPDATE BUS_STOPS SET LOCATION = 'test location name' WHERE BUS_STOP_ID = CurrentRowID;
END;
```

I'm trying to update LOCATION field within the same table when both LATITUDE and LONGITUDE fields are updated or inserted, but it doesn't seem to be working. And do I need to use bus_stops.bus_stop_id where CurrentRowID is?

Comment: This is because you are saying "Before update on BUS_STOPS, do something which includes Update of BUS_STOPS". You cannot do this and hence the error.

Comment: But AFTER update would cause table mutation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign the new value, not update the table:

```
create or replace TRIGGER fill_coordinates
  BEFORE UPDATE OR DELETE OR INSERT ON bus_stops
  FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN ( (NEW.latitude <> OLD.latitude OR NEW.longitude <> NEW.longitude ) AND ( NEW.longitude IS NOT NULL AND NEW.latitude IS NOT NULL) )
BEGIN  
  :new.LOCATION := 'test location name';
END;
```

But it doesn't make sense to do this in a `DELETE` trigger. You probably should remove the `OR DELETE` option from the trigger definition.

Comment: Is this Oracle SQL syntax? This trigger returns: _invalid use of bind variable_ (due to colons in the WHEN clause) and also requires to use := between BEGIN and END. If I remove these things I still get _expression is of wrong type_

Comment: @Aleksej: a right, thanks Btw: a "semicolon" is `;` the `:` is a "colon"

Comment: @JanisOzolins: that was an error on my side. Aleksej is right. The `:` is not valid in the `WHEN` condition.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - The trigger compiles but doesn't work when `LONGITUDE` or `LATITUDE` fields are updated. **Trigger 'USER.FILL_COORDINATES' is invalid and failed re-validation**

Comment: @JanisOzolins Do you see a "Trigger created with compilation warnings" when you create the trigger? What does `show errors` give you after creating the trigger?

Comment: @JanisOzolins The trigger compiles and works well on a test table. The issue could be in your table structure, please post it

Comment: @Aleksej - at line 2,3 **PL/SQL: Statement ignored** and at line 2,20 **PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type**

Comment: @JanisOzolins: sounds as if `LOCATION` is not defined as a `varchar`.

Comment: God bless you!!! I forgot it's a `SDO_GEOMETRY` object so I had to put `LATITUDE` and `LONGITUDE` in this object. Everything works perfectly now. Thank you!!!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i have some doubts, can you clear out some of my doubts?